# URL rewriting with pagination not working .htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, pagination

I have this following url `index.php?page=1` i want it to be `index.php/page/1`.

so far i have this

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^page/([^/]*)$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

and my pagination link looks like this:

```
$numbers.='<li><a class="active" href="?page='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a></span></li>'
```

If I use that it doesn't rewrite the Url.

and if i change my pagination to

```
$numbers.='<li><a class="active" href="?page/'.$i.'">'.$i.'</a></span></li>'
```

pagination stopped working and my result displays weirdly. Any idea why is this happening ?

Comment: Do you want it to be `index.php/page/1`  or `/page/1`?

Comment: You should use: `<a class="active" href="/page/'.$i.'">'.$i.'</a>`

Comment: The pagination not working .

Answer (score 0):

You can use following RewriteRule:

```
RewriteRule ^index.php/page/([0-9]+)$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

And links:

```
<li><a class="active" href="/index.php/page/'.$i.'">'.$i.'</a></li>
```

Or exclude `index.php/` from both if you dont want it in our links.

**UPDATE:**

ok, if you really need your pagination link look like `"?page/2"` you can delete the rewrite rule and use following instead of `$_GET['page']`: `intval(explode("?page/", $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"])[1])` - this basically splits URL by ?page/ and returns anything behind it as integrer - works in PHP >= 5.4. btw. this is VERY bad implementation of pagination link structure... but it will work

Comment: I am using` $_GET['page']` to get the page variable.so if i change this the pagination will stop working

Comment: or what if i want it jst to be `index.php/1` ? actually i want `?=` to be erased from my url when using pagination

Comment: in that case following RewriteRule should work: `RewriteRule ^index.php/([0-9]+)$ index.php?page=$1 [L]`

Comment: what should my link look like because it won't seem to get my link all by it self right ?